# Increase the size of the area where a ContactEvent for a Line is recognized

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I use lines to connect multiple UI Elements. This lines are rather thin. Now I want to add further information if the user clicks on a line. But as I remarked during testing, it is quite difficult to hit a line, since they are thin.

Now I'd like to increase the area of each line in which a contact event is recognized without increasing the visible line. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a control that consists of a grid with and your desired line with your desired touch space as the Margin.  Set the grid background to transparent so it will hit test, and hook all of you contacts to the grid, not the line.